# Width is changing but not height for images

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a "wrapper", an id that automatically resizes an image (in a slider) to fit the predetermined width and height. As of now, the images automatically resizes the width but not the height, I cant for the life of me think of a solution to this. Here's the code.

The CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px;   
}

.imgC {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!--- Image Slider -->

<div id="wrapper">
  <div><img class="imgC" src="img/main.jpg" alt="First slide"></div>
  <div><img class="imgC" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Second slide"></div>
  <div><img class="imgC" src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Third slide"></div>
</div>
```

If it helps to mention, I'm using slick by Ken Wheeler for the slider js. But even when I remove the code for the slider I still cant resize height (so i'm guessing that's not the issue.) Here's the js related to the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.thing').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000

      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you add the slick jquery code running the slider to the post? 
*Wild guess: **adaptiveHeight: true** is missing from your slick fn*

Comment: I've edited the question and removed the slider code. The height still wont change.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I'm asking for the js related with the slider. Can you add that to your post?

Answer (score 2):

You must write

```
<img src="theSource" style="width:30px;height:30px;" />
```

Inline styling will always take precedence over CSS styling. The width and height attributes are being overridden by your stylesheet, so you need to switch to this format.

Comment: That's worked, but I cant change/add code for each individual image, is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: In that case making ids are good option as they have higher priority compared to classes and style would not be overlapped. Upvote appreciated

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've made the id as seen from my above post, yet the height still wont change, which is odd. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: #wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px; }

Comment: Try  - ```height: auto;```

Comment: Height auto resizes according to the width, but I want a predetermined width and height of 400 x 450. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my quesiton. It seems the max-width and max-height styles applied to the image directly took the parents attributes, which in this case was a non-styled `<div>`. After removing the `<div>` for each image, the code worked. The edited code should look like this:

CSS:

```
.imgC {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!--- Image Slider -->

<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="imgC" src="img/main.jpg" alt="First slide">
  <img class="imgC" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  <img class="imgC" src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
```